# How to Delete Running Python Script

Tags: python

I made a program and I want to add a updating system. It checks that is there any update from a website and if there is an update, it downloads new file and overwrites new file on itself.

.py file works. It deletes itself through os.unlink method and saves new file instead of old file. Then, it opens new version and closes itself.
But, when I run its .exe file (pyinstaller), I got that error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

How can I solve it ?

Edit: I turned it into exe file through pyinstaller and typing that command:

```
pyinstaller file.py
```

Codes from my script:

```
os.unlink(sys.argv[0]) # The program is deleting itself.

if sys.argv[0].endswith(".py"): #detects that is itself an exe or a python file
    urlretrieve("http://version.information.site.com/newprogram.py", "newprogram.py") #download file as newprogram.py
    os.rename("newprogram.py", "program.py") #rename new file as program.py
    os.system("python program.py") #run new program
elif sys.argv[0].endswith(".exe"): #if it is a exe file
    urlretrieve("http://version.information.site.com/newprogram.exe",  "newprogram.exe") #download file as newprogram.exe
    os.rename("newprogram.exe", "program.exe") #rename new file as program.exe
    os.system("program.exe") #run new program
```

Comment: First surely you should be naming the new program as sys.argv[0]

Comment: Here's the process you normally follow to have a program that updates itself: Get a helper program (might be included as a resource within your main program). Run the helper program as a separate process. The helper program downloads the update to your program. Have the main program detect that the update is ready, then close itself (or prompt the user to close it because an update is ready). Have the helper detect when the original has closed, & replace the original with the update. Start the updated version from the helper, then quit the helper. The updated version can delete the helper now.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. But is there any way to solve this problem on main program ?

Answer (score 0):

this might be a lucky guess, i won't be able to test it on windows right now.

Unlocking a file handler from process is kind of "nasty process", [(article here)](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/selfdeletingexecutables/)
BUT
as file handler is already being open, so maybe, just maybe,
opening it again in python may merge with same system handler. Tried it on linux, works.

So try just overwritting it

```
with open('program.exe', 'wb') as f:  # or 'w' for *.py extension
    f.write( your downloaded data )
```

Comment: I got that error: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Answer (score -1):

Try running it with admin perms. The problem might lie withhow you turn it into an .exe. Could you please elaborate on that.Could you please also post you code, just the relevant bit.

Comment: It doesn't work. I editted my explanation. I added codes.